# Access files under a package in java

Tags: java, package

I have the package structure something like this

```
src
  main
    java
      com
        org
          -- Loader.java
    resources
      schemas
        -- a.schema
        -- b. schema
```

Now I want to be able to access the list of schemas under the schema folder which could vary with time from the Loader class. I package it as a jar and in runtime access all the files under the schema folder. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do this inside Loader.java:

```
InputStream in = Loader.class.getResourceAsStream("/data/schemas/a.schema");
```

The leading slash means from starting from the root of classpath (i.e. your JAR file).

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8, you should get it easily. See below code:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<Path> filePathStream = Files.walk(Paths.get("/data/schemas/"))) {
        List<File> filesInFolder = filePathStream.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                            .map(Path::toFile)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(filesInFolder);
    }

 }
```

}

here the try-with-resource constructs ensures that the stream is closed automatically after using.